# Compare two files and output the differences

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, diff

I am aware of `diff` and using loops but I just cant seem to really get what I need with diff. I'm basically looking to compare two files (file2.txt and file2.txt) and just get the output of what is missing between them.

Objective 1: Find what is missing in file2.txt from file1.txt

Objective 2: Find what is missing in either file. Some lines may exist in file2.txt that arent in file1.txt. I'd like to know about them as well.

`diff` only tells me that the two files arent the same, going line by line comparing the differences. What I need is a program that goes through the file, and doesn't discriminate by lines. If a line containing '/bin/mount' is found on line 2 of file1.txt and is found on line 59 of file2.txt, then I don't need to know about it. I only want to know what isn't there as a whole. Can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care about the line order, sort the files first. To see what lines are missing in what file, use `comm` instead of `diff`:

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: What a simple and easy command. Never knew about it. But how can I grep out only the unique entries from whatever column I want?

Comment: @unixpipe: Have you read `man comm`?

Comment: I just did now, apologies. I am able to suppress either columns. These are great answers. I wish I can answer you guys both because they are both right!

Answer (score 4):

> Objective 1: Find what is missing in file2.txt from file1.txt

With `grep`:

```
grep -xvFf file2.txt file1.txt
```

With `comm`:

```
comm -13 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

With `sort` and `uniq`:

```
sort file2.txt file2.txt file1.txt | uniq -u
```

> Objective 2: Find what is missing in either file. Some lines may exist
>   in file2.txt that arent in file1.txt. I'd like to know about them as
>   well.

With `grep`:

```
grep -xvFf file1.txt file2.txt; grep -xvFf file2.txt file1.txt
```

With `comm`:

```
comm -3 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) | tr -d '\t'
```

With `sort` and `uniq`:

```
sort file1.txt file2.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: You guys are the best

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to match the similarity percentage between two file

```
import numpy as np
def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    size_x = len(seq1) + 1
    size_y = len(seq2) + 1
    matrix = np.zeros ((size_x, size_y))
    for x in range(size_x):
        matrix [x, 0] = x
    for y in range(size_y):
        matrix [0, y] = y

    for x in range(1, size_x):
        for y in range(1, size_y):
            if seq1[x-1] == seq2[y-1]:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1, y-1],
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                )
            else:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1,y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1,y-1] + 1,
                    matrix[x,y-1] + 1
                )
    #print (matrix)
    return (matrix[size_x - 1, size_y - 1])

with open('original.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    str1=data.replace(' ', '')
with open('target.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    str2=data.replace(' ', '')
if(len(str1)>len(str2)):
    length=len(str1)
else:
    length=len(str2)
print(100-round((levenshtein(str1,str2)/length)*100,2),'% Similarity')
```

Create two files "original.txt" and "target.txt" in same directory with content.